visual-studio 2022 pytest testlauncher.py failing to launch
I have a pytest installed on virtual env in visual studio 2022. The tests run fine outside visual studio 2022, but the VS test explorer skips all tests with this error below thanks to a testlauncher.py script from vs internals, is there a way to just launch pytest against the test_xxx.py files in the test explorer? I was able to make a dotnet test to work by adding a VSTest target in the pyproj, wondering if there's a fix for test explorer? this is an expensive tool to no have a proper code to do just the basics 
platform win32 -- Python 3.12.4, pytest-8.2.2, pluggy-1.5.0
env1\Scripts\python.exe "C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\PYTHON\CORE\testlauncher.py" XXXX\ pytest "" 0 "" "" dummyfilename .\tests\test_optimization_host.py::test_bogus_endpoint --junitxml=XXX\TestResults\junitresults_e6fdf0a1-8aa1-4227-8f5c-f9bcc5b97e34.xml --rootdir=XXXX -o junit_logging=all -o junit_family=xunit1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\PYTHON\CORE\testlauncher.py", line 189, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\PYTHON\CORE\testlauncher.py", line 30, in main
    run(testRunner, coverage_file, test_file, args)
  File "C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\PYTHON\CORE\testlauncher.py", line 119, in run
    patch_translate_non_printable()
  File "C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\PYTHON\CORE\testlauncher.py", line 136, in patch_translate_non_printable
    translate_non_printable =  getattr(_pytest.compat, "_translate_non_printable")
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module '_pytest.compat' has no attribute '_translate_non_printable'
Results for pytest not found xxxx\TestResults\junitresults_e6fdf0a1-8aa1-4227-8f5c-f9bcc5b97e34.xml
========== Test run finished: 1 Tests (0 Passed, 0 Failed, 1 Skipped) run in 176 ms ==========
========== Starting test discovery ==========
Starting pytest discovery for the XXXX project. This can take up to 60 seconds.
cd xxxx
set PYTHONPATH=XXX
\env1\Scripts\python.exe C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\PYTHON\CORE\PythonFiles\testing_tools\run_adapter.py discover pytest --output-file ERROR: failed to patch pytest, _pytest.compat._translate_non_printable

========== Test discovery finished: 1 Tests found in 1.5 sec ==========


Currently you need to install pytest-8.0.2 instead of any newer versions
see: https://github.com/microsoft/PTVS/issues/7853
